# Two limits problems (statement and l'hopital)

Tags: calculus, limits

> Given: $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty }\frac{x^2+p(x)}{1-x^2}=5$ $p(x)$ is a polynomial.
> What can we conclude about $p(x)$ power?

What I did was just solve an equation, $\frac{x^2+y}{1-x^2}=5$ then we get $y=5-6x^2$ then I applied it to the limit ($p(x)$ instead of y)
$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty }\frac{x^2+(5-6x^2)}{1-x^2}=5$ after calculating the limit I got $5=5$ . So the power is $2$.

> "A student claims that there is a one and only polynomial that fulfills the questions answer"

I think that the answer is right because if the power is greater than $2$ we will get $+\infty$ and I belive that the Coefficient also has role but I am not sure , can anyone explain this part better?.

The second question is:

> given $f(x)=\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x-x^2}$ and also given $
> g(x)=
> \begin{cases}
>  0&\text {if  } \, x= 1\\
>  0.5&\text{if }\, x≠1\\
>      \end{cases}$
> also given the limits of the functions: $\lim \limits_{x \to 1 }f(x)=A$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to 1 }f(g(x))=B$
> find the values of A and B (the answer can be " the limit does not exist")

so for A it wasn't much of a problem as I used l'hopital.$\lim \limits_{x \to 1 }\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x-x^2}$ after doing l'hopital rule we get $\lim \limits_{x \to 1 }\frac{\pi cos(\pi x)}{1-2x}$ $=1=A$
for the second part of the question I got confused because I didn't know if when we do ${x \to 1 }$ I should get $0$ of $g(x)$ or get $0.5$ of $g(x)$ as when we do a limit we only get close to the number according to what I know , not exactly $1$.

if we look at it as in $x=1$ we get $\lim \limits_{x \to 1 }f(0)$ = $\lim \limits_{x \to 1 }\frac{sin(0)}{0-0}$ and then even l'hopital won't help

and if we look at it as in $x≠1$ we get $\lim \limits_{x \to 1 }f(0.5)$ = $\lim \limits_{x \to 1 }\frac{sin(\frac {\pi}2)}{0.5-0.25}$ = 4

My question is , is my way correct? and from the second part how should I look at the function when the limit is to $1$? should it be $x=1$ or  $x≠1$? and of course about the first part.

Appreciate all the help , and sorry for the English mistakes.

Comment: Hints: for the first part you can add any polynomial of the form $ax + b$ to the numerator without affecting the limit; for the second part, $\lim_{x\to c} h(x)$ does not depend on $h(c)$ (check the $\varepsilon{-}\delta$ definition).

Comment: @RobArthan If he adds a linear polynomial, the limit will $\frac{1}{-1}=-1\;$ ...he **must** add a polynomial like the one he wrote in his question: any polynomial of the form $\;-6x^2+bx+c\;$...and thus his answer is accurate: the power of $\;p\;$ is $\;2\;$ .

Comment: I have edited your post @Adamrk but for future post, I suggest putting only one focused query in it.

Comment: @donantonio: I think you missed the point of my comment. The point is that the solution is not unique because adding a linear polynomial to the denominator of a solution gives another solution.

Comment: @RobArthan You wrote to the OP that he can add a linear polynomial *to the numerator* ...and the solution is unique since it **must be** $\;\deg p=2\;$ , which was the question. Of course, there are infinite quadratic polynomials that can be $\;p\;$ , but that wasn't the question...

Comment: "A student claims that there is ... only one polynomial that ...". "I think that ... is right ... but I am not sure" How is my correct hint that shows the solution is not unique wrong? The first part of the question is not just about the degree of the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part two, the limit is different:

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin\pi x}{x-x^2}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\pi\cos\pi x}{1-2x}=\frac{-\pi}{-1}=\pi$$

The rest of part two and part one looks fine: the function $\;f(g(x))=4\;$ is a constant for any $\;x\neq1\;$ , thus that it is the limit when $\;x\to1\;$ .